# Flask Error: “Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL” (Login and Home Page)

Tags: mongodb, flask

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
if current_user.is_authenticated:
    posts=mongo.db.articles
    #allpost=posts.find().limit(5)
    it=current_user.user_json['interest']
    allpost=posts.find( {'NewsType': it } ).limit(10)
    #flash(session['email'])

    return render_template('home.html', posts=allpost)
return render_template('login.html', title='Login',form=LoginForm())
```

This is my code for the Home Page

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
if current_user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
form = LoginForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    users = mongo.db.users
    loginuser_json = users.find_one({'email': form.email.data})
    if loginuser_json and bcrypt.check_password_hash(loginuser_json['password'], form.password.data):
        # Create a custom user and pass it to login_user:
        loginuser = User(loginuser_json)
        login_user(loginuser,duration=d)
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect(url_for('home'))
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    else:
        flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check username and password', 'danger')
return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```

and this for the login route

When i write localhost:5000 in the browser it opens Login Page (because if user is not authenticated it should go to login page first)

But when i try to login from this page , it is giving an error "Method Not Allowed.The method is not allowed for the requested URL."

What should i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, it is not clear which code is called when the method is GET (usually when rendering your login page) and which is to be called when method is POST (called when you are submitting your form). To remove the mix up, do like this in your login

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    # code that runs for both GET and POST goes here
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            #authenticate user and redirect to next page/home page
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form) #this runs when method is get
```

Note the indentation and the respective code running under it

**NOTE** on your login template ensure the form method is post something like this

```
<form method=post>
  <dl>
    {{ render_field(form.email) }}
    {{ render_field(form.password) }}
    {{form.hidden_tag()}} 
  </dl>
  <input type=submit value=Submit>
</form>
```

Lastly, on you home page, you have two routes that form the url_for(home) - though I do not think this is where your error is coming from - ensure both of them accept the method POST if you intend to use it there

```
@app.route("/",methods=['GET', 'POST'])#add post on this route
@app.route("/home",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
```

Hope this helps you sort out the error

Comment: Also I would recommend to replace the return render_template('login.html'....) in the home function to an else return redirect to login. At least that is what I think is meant to happen there.

Comment: Thank you soo much For the recommendation and help

Comment: @adnan you are welcome, If the answer solves the issue for you remember to accept it, otherwise let us know if you need further assistance

Comment: Yes , the answer solve my issue. I have accepted it but it says your response has recorded but wont show because i have less than 15 reputation score.

Comment: @adnan Accepting is the clicking on the Grey tick between the upvote and downvote. Only the upvote and downvote need more reputation. (And you do get a reputation of 2 when you accept an answer )